# string splitting and truncating with different formatting of incoming strings

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, str-replace

What I have:
a string that says "Tue Aug 7, 2012 to Tue Aug 28, 2012"

What I want:
a string that says "Aug 7 - Aug 28"

The only catch is sometimes I have this as a string:

"Fri Aug 31, 2012 7:30pm to 9:30pm"

and I would need this as a result:
"Aug 31"

This is info that is coming from a Google calendar feed, so the incoming string is different based on whether user has put in start time, etc.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: So the incoming format can vary? What constants do you have  - will there always be a "to", for example?

Comment: i have difficulty believing google calendar can not provide a more standard date format.

Comment: Does google calendar not offer an XML feed that would have these all broken down into nodes that you more easily manipulate?

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  The above two examples are the only two different ways that I will have the strings.  This is only one small part of the whole incoming stream of info from Google, so I won't be changing how the data is received.

Comment: The regex `"/(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\ [0-9]+/"` would match the appropriate dates. You can remove duplicates manually, and then join the remainder.

Comment: To be most clear:  If I have an event that is multiple days, there is not a "time" associated with it.  If I have a one day event, there is a "time" associated with it.  In either case, I need to do the above truncations.

Comment: no-I am saying that there is a whole lot of other stuff going on with other aspects of the incoming stream that I don't want to have to go in and change just for this.

Comment: Google Calendar does offer XML, ICAL, and RSS.

Comment: yes...smacks head...this is what I have to work with.

Comment: @Pekka-yes-the above formatting will always be the same.

Comment: @arxanas, I used your regex with the `preg_match_all` function in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) function to make the logic easier:

```
$str1 = "Tue Aug 7, 2012 to Tue Aug 28, 2012";
$str2 = "Fri Aug 31, 2012 7:30pm to 9:30pm";

$pattern = '/(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) \d+/';
$numMatches = preg_match_all($pattern, $str1, $dates);

if ($numMatches == 1) // case 2
    echo $dates[0][0];
else // case 1
    echo $dates[0][0]." - ".$dates[0][1];
```

[**DEMO (change $str1 to $str2 in `preg_match_all` to test case 2)**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8b8de978622c32cecaed8c91ccaba9ce4ba4841f)

This will work whenever there are one or more dates with the format `MON D` or `MON DD` in your string.  It doesn't matter how the rest of the string is formatted, only that the month and day exist.

Answer (score 1):

#### Case 1

```
$string = 'Fri Aug 31, 2012 7:30pm to 9:30pm';

$pieces = explode(' to ', $string);

$d1 = strtotime($pieces[0]);

if(isset($pieces[1])) {
    $d2 = strtotime($pieces[1]);
    if(date('M j', $d1) == date('M j', strtotime($pieces[1], $d1))) {
        echo date('M j', $d1);
    }
    else echo date('M j', $d1) . " - " . date('M j', $d2);
}
else {
    echo date('M j', $d1);
}
```

**Result:** Aug 31

#### Case 2

```
$string = 'Tue Aug 7, 2012 to Tue Aug 28, 2012';
```

**Result:** Aug 7 - Aug 28

#### Case 3

```
$string = 'Tue Aug 7, 2012';
```

**Result:** Aug 7

Comment: For some strange reason this seems to echo back the end date always as Dec 31?

Comment: @Joel could you elaborate? Works fine in sandbox: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4e8ae2e77af62f6587b8b9b5a8ecff42a3168cf6

Comment: Not much else to say about it...If I echoed $string, I would get the accurate string, but echoing the date would give Dec 31 end date.

Comment: @Joel are you reusing the code from from Case 1 and replacing the `$string`?

Answer (score 1):

Check this variant out:

$in = "Tue Aug 7, 2012 to Tue Aug 28, 2012";
//$in = "Fri Aug 31, 2012 7:30pm to 4:30am";

```
$reg = '~(\w{3}) (\w{3}) (\d{1,2}), (\d{4}) (\d{1,2}:\d{2}(?:pm|am) )?to (?:(\w{3}) (\w{3}) (\d{1,2}), (\d{4})|(\d{1,2}:\d{2}(?:pm|am)))~i';
$in = preg_replace_callback($reg, function($m) {
    if (!$m[6] && !$m[9]) {
        return "{$m[2]} {$m[3]}";
    }
    else return "{$m[2]} {$m[3]} - {$m[7]} {$m[8]}";
}, $in);


echo $in;
```

For `"Tue Aug 7, 2012 to Tue Aug 28, 2012"` prints `Aug 7 - Aug 28`, and for `"Fri Aug 31, 2012 7:30pm to 4:30am"` you get `Aug 31`.

Comment: Thanks.  I need to figure out how to make this work with the array I'm returning now (a newbie issue) but I think this will work.  Thanks again!

Comment: I am getting 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION' in the second line

Comment: Right, it's time to update to PHP 5.3 ;)